# Can we retrieve the iphone user pass code on a jailbroken device?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, passcode, mobile-security

Simple question, Is it possible to retrieve the iphone lock screen passcode if we jailbreak the device?

Comment: If you mean, is it sitting somewhere in plain text that you can access, then no, definitely not. The passcode is passed to the Secure Enclave and used to decrypt the key bag. Is it possible to attack the Lock Screen process to intercept the passcode that is entered?  Probably.

Comment: @Paulw11 catching the passcode while they enter it is definitely possible, many custom lockscreen tweaks work(ed) like that.